# PrimeFaces Filter Activated

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want that the filter is already activated when the page is loaded but I don't find any attribute that let me do that. The selectItem "Not Finished" is the one that should be activated. Here is my code:

```
<ui:define name="columnFinished">

        <p:column filterBy="#{tarea.hasBeenFinished()}"
            headerText="#{msgs.fechaFinalizacion}" filterMatchMode="equals">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('tasksTable').filter()">
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Not Finished" itemValue="false" />
                </p:selectOneButton>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{userBean.formatDate(tarea.finished)}" />
        </p:column>

</ui:define>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `value="false"` as attribute to the `p:selectOneButton`, this way when the page is loaded, `Not Finished` is set as default value for the filter

Comment: Using value="false" as it matches "" and "false" both buttons are clicked. Any idea?